# Como mudar o valor de um botão para o valor de um array?

Tags: javascript

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]Tentei usar getElementeById mas não está funcionando.

## HTML Quiz

```
        <div class="buttons"> <!--Creating four button element for four options-->
            <button id="btn0"><span id="choice0"></span></button> 
            <button id="btn1"><span id="choice1"></span></button>
            <button id="btn2"><span id="choice2"></span></button>
            <button id="btn3"><span id="choice3"></span></button>
        </div>

function quiz(){
    document.getElementById("choice0").value = array[index][1];
    document.getElementById("choice1").value = array[index][2];
    document.getElementById("choice2").value = array[index][3];
    document.getElementById("choice3").value = array[index][4];
    }
```

var array = [
        ["Quem descobriu o Brasil?","Cabral", "Paes", "Garotinho","Lula"],
...
]

EDIT: Fui Agora no console log dá uma olhada, parece que o erro é esse: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of undefined no array [index](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8VL20.png).

Comment: Dá algum erro ? O que dá `console.log(array)` ? Sugiro que crie um [exemplo Mínimo, Completo e Verificável do problema](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) para que seja facil a comunidade indicar o problema e respetiva solução.

Comment: simplesmente não parece nada, nem dá erro no console

Comment: Você já respondeu à primeira pergunta que eu fiz. Falta agora responder à segunda e seguir o conselho que eu dei de montar um exemplo que mostre o problema.

Comment: Em que momento/ação(ou seja, quando) é para alterar esses valores ?

Comment: @luizricardo6n eu tentei colocar como uma das primeiras ações, mas continua aparecendo nada no botão, eu acho que nesse caso a posição não importa

Comment: Onde foi definido o `index` e com que valor ?

Comment: nenhum valor, eu usei ele para pegar a posição do meu vetor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você está tentando alterar o valor do conteúdo do `span` e o texto dessa tag está contido no `innerHTML`. Para funcionar normalmente altere de `value` para `innerHTML`:

```
function quiz(){
    document.getElementById("choice0").innerHTML = array[index][1];
    document.getElementById("choice1").innerHTML = array[index][2];
    document.getElementById("choice2").innerHTML = array[index][3];
    document.getElementById("choice3").innerHTML = array[index][4];
}
```

Espero ter ajudado.